# VB.NET log in form using MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Can someone help me with the following please.

I have created a database called dbhr and a table in it called user with two fields 'username' and 'password' having VARCHAR data type.
I have a log in form with two textboxes (tbxUsername,tbxPassword) and an OK button. I have connected my database to authenticate the username and password. But it always give me wrong password message. I don't know where I went wrong.
Please help.

I use MySQL Workbench 6.1

Thanks in advance.

Here is the VB.NET log in button code.

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Login

    Dim mydbcon As MySqlConnection
    Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand

    ' TODO: Insert code to perform custom authentication using the provided username and password 
    ' (See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=35339).  
    ' The custom principal can then be attached to the current thread's principal as follows: 
    '     My.User.CurrentPrincipal = CustomPrincipal
    ' where CustomPrincipal is the IPrincipal implementation used to perform authentication. 
    ' Subsequently, My.User will return identity information encapsulated in the CustomPrincipal object
    ' such as the username, display name, etc.

    Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
        mydbcon = New MySqlConnection
        mydbcon.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=rootword;database=hrdb"
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

        Try
            mydbcon.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "select * from user where username= ' " & tbxUsername.Text & "' and password= ' " & tbxPassword.Text & "' "
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, mydbcon)
            reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

            Dim count As Integer
            count = 0
            While reader.Read
                count = count + 1

            End While

            If count = 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Username and password are correct")
            ElseIf count > 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Username and password are duplicate")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Username and password are wrong")
            End If
            mydbcon.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            mydbcon.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Please click the following links to see the database table records and data types.

Click [here](https://0466f663-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/ssdfdsfdsfdsfdsf/home/Database%20table%20with%20records%20and%20log%20in%20result.jpg?attachauth=ANoY7cpxgiS2sYPvcmMHKeiPhoXRjBZmKxJRddHzAx1rZe9bfwyejD5rDlQEIRPYxjWBwUHUEdTaVEeNs4Hm7vtgmq6iDpMAtpiVCQZu_BRKkcOyU-dal57zzewAbDYKY1F4GJ5Jj-mZljzcniXeGDEEts1McopzhAYtHu7jxvmxPJosu-OL9MmTIZLHcocw7-ZoXCLsBi5X5Uz27kdDdP6U-fetnOgG0i8l2PzJe4MgXOwmuuua7Lb3qo3VnfPC9p6ZH-OXgtb0vQu-JMmb-lhzLMYOukMnwg%3D%3D&attredirects=0)!

Comment: Why don't you place your button code in this post instead of providing a link to some download site?

Comment: Button code added. I also had to provide db settings that's why I attach screenshot.

Comment: OK... now what message do you always get? BTW... by the looks of things you are storing password unencrypted is this your intention?

Comment: I am very much new to MySQL and I don't know all the security features and things I should take in to consideration while creating database. I just made a table as I learn from YouTube videos. I thing I could successfully create a database. I don't know about encryption and all that, please give me some information about encryption if you could. I gave username as abc and password as ab but message I got is 'Username and password are wrong'. But they exist in the database.

Comment: Sorry have been away... By way of encryption I had in mind to encrypt the password before saving it in the database. So in the code that you use to create a user. The user would enter their chosen password which you encrypt before saving it in the database. In the login code you would again encrypt the entered password and compare the encrypted password with the one in the database. There are many examples of encryption on the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some extra spaces in the line

```vb
Query = "select * from user where username= ' " & tbxUsername.Text & "' and password= ' " & tbxPassword.Text & "' "
```

which I would change to

```vb
Query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '{0}' AND password = '{1}'", Me.tbxUsername.Text.Trim(), Me.tbxPassword.Text.Trim())
```

I would use `String.Format()` to make it clearer, less chance to overlook those extra spaces.

Comment: Cheers. Can you tell me where I left extra spaces? If I remove the extra spaces then is there any disadvantages of using my format over your's? I just want know whether my codding is worse. :)

Comment: ... `where username= ' "` between the ' and ", likewise on the password.

Comment: The extra space in `username = ' {0}'` is very obvious compared with `where username= ' "`. It's a matter of preference in a simple case like this, though the clarity I think more than justifies the use of String.Format. Functionally, they are the same.

Comment: @user3765415 By the way, did this solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Your code worked perfectly and after removing extra spaces as you suggested my code worked too. @Mych mentioned about my password which is unencrypted. I don't know how to make it encrypted. Be the way, My problem is solved.